# is it possible to refer to an EC2 Elastic IP Address from within EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a cluster of EC2 machines that need to be able to refer to each other.  Using their private IP address works but leads to problems whenever one of the instances restarts.

So, I tried Elastic IP addresses so that my servers have fixed addresses.  The problem is that I do not not seem to be able to refer to the machines by their Elastic IPs from with the cloud.

So, from outside the cloud I ping elasticIp and it works.  I then ssh to another of my EC2 machines and when I ping that same elasticIp it fails.  But, I can ping that machine's private address.

Bottom line: are Elastic IPs only outward facing?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you can ping an instance will depend on what rules you have setup for the security group the instance belongs to.

Instances can use elastic ips to talk to each other, however you will be charged for this data transfer at the regional data transfer rate even if the instances are actually in the same availability zone (data transfer using internal ips is free in this case).

Comment: I don't think that's relevant in this case.  I have machines A and B in the same group.  Sitting on A I can ping B by its private address but not by its Elastic Address.  Security group doesn't change between these two cases.  I should mention my security setting is to allow all traffic between my nodes.

Comment: I do agree with your comment about being charged for data transfer..which was a surprise and a killer for us.

Comment: amazon may well be blocking ICMP traffic at the external<->internal network boundary (which is the one you are crossing given that you are being charged for it).